# About the use of vue3 props parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Receive all values through one parameter of props.

```
const props = defineProps({
    customSearchConfig: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  })

  const backgroundColor = computed(() => {
    return props.customSearchConfig.backgroundColor
  })
```

separate use

```
const props = defineProps({
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: '请输入'
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String,
      default: '#f4f5f7'
    }
  })
```

I saw the usage of "computed" in someone else's code, but I don't understand the advantages of doing so.Because I don't know what parameters the current component needs, I have to look at the documentation for all of them.

Which of the above two methods is better, what are the advantages and disadvantages, and which one do you all use?

Comment: The question is too unspecific. There are no advantages or disadvantages, it always depends on the case. Both can be used. For only 2 props the second snippet makes more sense

Comment: I found that a colleague would use computed to modify the value of the object passed in by props. This was a violation of vue's single stream. This is not unreasonable @Estus Flask 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76180780/vue3-computed-return-object

Comment: You didn't mention in this question that you want to change these properties, this changes everything.