# vue3 computed return object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I see some people playing with code like this. Does this break Vue's single data stream? I don't think computed should be used that way either

**Child component:**

```
<template>

<el-switch
  v-model="customConfig.switchValue"
  active-color="#13ce66"
  @change="customConfig.change"
  inactive-color="#ff4949">
</el-switch>

</template>

...
    props: {
      customConfig: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({})
      }
    },
    setup(props, { emit }) {
      const customConfig= computed(() => {
        return Object.assign({}, props.customConfig) //is right?
      })

     const change = (e) => {
        console.log( e)
      }
      return {
        customConfig,
      }
    }
```

**Parent component:**

```
    <custom-switch
      :customConfig="customConfig"
    />

const customTabsConfig = reactive({
   switchValue:false,
   change: (index: number) => {
       console.log(index)
   },

})
```

Isn't the value of computed changed by other values? If you use it like this, won’t it break the data flow of the parent-child component if you use it in the child component?

Comment: "won’t it break the data flow" - it will. A child isn't supposed to mutate a prop. That you wrap it with a computed means that it can be overwritten by a parent without notice. You likely need to use proper two-way binding